# Why does RecordSelectionFormula suddenly reject my formula?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a VB6 application using Crystal Reports XI.

After almost two years suddenly I cannot set `RecordSelectionFormula` anymore. The error message says, that Basic syntax is not allowed in record selection formula.

The formula is `{article.id} = 1234`.

I've tripple checked that formula. It works fine in the Crystal Reports designer, but even if I save that formula and change it at runtime to `{article.id} = 1235` I get the same error message. Also there's no reason why this worked the whole time and suddenly not.

After googling I find that a few users have the same problem, but since Crystal Reports 11 and VB6 are somewhat antiquated, nobody seems to have solution, except updating to a newer versions of Crystal Reports or Visual Basic.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but have you tried passing the argument as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you now running on Vista? Crystal XI has known issues with it and there's no patch. However, Crystal XI Release 2 is a free download for existing users of Crystal Reports XI and combined with the subsequent service packs should solve some issues :

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/service_packs/crxir2.asp

There is also this, extracted from a google cache of an old CR knowledge base entry :

> KBase Article ID:c2018734
>
> Article refers to:Crystal Reports XI 
>   Symptom
>
> When a Report Designer Component (RDC)
>   XI web or Windows application  passes
>   a record selection formula to a report
>   at run time, the following  error
>   message appears:
>
> "Basic syntax is not supported in
>   group/record selection formula"
>
> Why does this error message appear and
>   how do you resolve it?  Resolution
>
> The error message appears after an RDC
>   application has been upgraded  from a
>   previous version. As a result, the
>   record selection formula is  being
>   interpreted as Basic syntax, even if
>   it is not Basic syntax.
>
> To resolve the error message, add
>   these lines of code to your 
>   application so that they are executed
>   before the record selection  formula
>   is passed to the report:
>
> ' report is the name of the 'Report'
>   object
>
> ' sets the record selection formula to
>   be interpreted as Crystal syntax
>
> report.FormulaSyntax = 0 ' Use
>   crCrystalSyntaxFormula value

Comment: I did no such upgrade, but setting `FormulaSyntax` to `crCrystalSyntaxFormula ` did the trick. Thank you.